# Can't upgrade Magento 2.2.4 to 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2.2.4 to 2.2.5 with composer.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php composer.phar require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 --no-update
php composer.phar update
```

The update is failing with the following errors

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/magento2ce 2.2.4 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2ce[2.2.4].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 requires magento/framework 101.0.5 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.5].
    - don't install magento/framework 101.0.5|remove magento/magento2ce 2.2.4
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.5].
```

Here is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "magento/magento2ce",
    "description": "Magento 2 (Open Source)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.4",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "^2.7.7",
        "zendframework/zend-code": "~3.1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-server": "^2.6.1",
        "zendframework/zend-soap": "^2.6.0",
        "zendframework/zend-uri": "^2.5.1",
        "zendframework/zend-validator": "^2.6.0",
        "zendframework/zend-crypt": "^2.6.0",
        "zendframework/zend-console": "^2.6.0",
        "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "^2.7",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "~2.7.12",
        "zendframework/zend-text": "^2.6.0",
        "zendframework/zend-i18n": "^2.7.3",
        "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "^2.6.3",
        "zendframework/zend-view": "^2.8.1",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "^2.7.8",
        "zendframework/zend-json": "^2.6.1",
        "zendframework/zend-config": "^2.6.0",
        "zendframework/zend-form": "^2.10.0",
        "zendframework/zend-di": "^2.6.1",
        "zendframework/zend-serializer": "^2.7.2",
        "zendframework/zend-log": "^2.9.1",
        "zendframework/zend-http": "^2.6.0",
        "zendframework/zend-db": "^2.8.2",
        "zendframework/zend-captcha": "^2.7.1",
        "zendframework/zend-session": "^2.7.3",
        "magento/zendframework1": "~1.13.0",
        "colinmollenhour/credis": "1.8.2",
        "colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract": "1.3.4",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "1.10.4",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file": "1.4",
        "composer/composer": "1.4.1",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
        "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.7.0",
        "pelago/emogrifier": "^2.0.0",
        "tubalmartin/cssmin": "4.1.1",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": ">=0.1.11",
        "braintree/braintree_php": "3.28.0",
        "symfony/console": "~2.3, !=2.7.0",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~2.1",
        "symfony/process": "~2.1",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.*",
        "tedivm/jshrink": "~1.3.0",
        "magento/composer": "~1.2.0",
        "lib-libxml": "*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-spl": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "ext-bcmath": "*",
        "ext-hash": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-xsl": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
        "ramsey/uuid": "~3.7.3",
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.2.4",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.2.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "replace": {
        "magento/module-marketplace": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-admin-notification": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-analytics": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-authorization": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-authorizenet": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-backend": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-backup": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-braintree": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-bundle": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-cache-invalidate": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-captcha": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-catalog": "102.0.4",
        "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-catalog-import-export": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule": "101.0.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-catalog-search": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-widget": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-checkout": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-checkout-agreements": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-cms": "102.0.4",
        "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-config": "101.0.4",
        "magento/module-configurable-import-export": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-configurable-product": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-configurable-product-sales": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-contact": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-cookie": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-cron": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-currency-symbol": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-customer": "101.0.4",
        "magento/module-customer-analytics": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-customer-import-export": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-deploy": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-developer": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-dhl": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-directory": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-downloadable": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-eav": "101.0.3",
        "magento/module-email": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-encryption-key": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-fedex": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-gift-message": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-google-adwords": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-google-analytics": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-google-optimizer": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-grouped-import-export": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-grouped-product": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-import-export": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-indexer": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-instant-purchase": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-integration": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-layered-navigation": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-media-storage": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-msrp": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-multishipping": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-newsletter": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-offline-payments": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-offline-shipping": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-page-cache": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-payment": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-paypal": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-persistent": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-product-alert": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-product-video": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-quote": "101.0.3",
        "magento/module-quote-analytics": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-release-notification": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-reports": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-require-js": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-review": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-review-analytics": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-robots": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-rss": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-rule": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-sales": "101.0.3",
        "magento/module-sales-analytics": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-sales-inventory": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-sales-rule": "101.0.2",
        "magento/module-sales-sequence": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-sample-data": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-search": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-security": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-send-friend": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-shipping": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-signifyd": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-sitemap": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-store": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-swagger": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-swatches": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-swatches-layered-navigation": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-tax": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-tax-import-export": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-theme": "100.2.4",
        "magento/module-translation": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-ui": "101.0.4",
        "magento/module-ups": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-url-rewrite": "101.0.3",
        "magento/module-user": "101.0.2",
        "magento/module-usps": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-variable": "100.2.3",
        "magento/module-vault": "101.0.2",
        "magento/module-version": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-webapi": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-webapi-security": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-weee": "100.2.1",
        "magento/module-widget": "101.0.2",
        "magento/module-wishlist": "101.0.2",
        "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "100.2.0",
        "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": "100.2.2",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.2.2",
        "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.2.3",
        "magento/language-de_de": "100.2.0",
        "magento/language-en_us": "100.2.0",
        "magento/language-es_es": "100.2.0",
        "magento/language-fr_fr": "100.2.0",
        "magento/language-nl_nl": "100.2.0",
        "magento/language-pt_br": "100.2.0",
        "magento/language-zh_hans_cn": "100.2.0",
        "magento/framework": "101.0.4",
        "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "1.4.3",
        "components/jquery": "1.11.0",
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "5.6.14",
        "components/jqueryui": "1.10.4",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.1.0",
        "tinymce/tinymce": "3.4.7"
    },
    "extra": {
        "component_paths": {
            "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
            "components/jquery": [
                "lib/web/jquery.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
            ],
            "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
            "components/jqueryui": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
            ],
            "twbs/bootstrap": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"
            ],
            "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce"
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        },
        "data-migration-tool": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool"
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the upgrade is failing?

Comment: What's with the replace node in your composer.json ? I have nothing of the kind.

Comment: This should be a standard composer.json file, all I have done is run `composer.phar require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 --no-update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try removing everything that is already required by `magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5` from your own `composer.json` and run it again. Yours seems a little excessive. Then try this command:

`composer update magento/product-community-edition:2.2.5 --with-dependencies`.

Comment: I have just tried that, however it won't update. `Package "magento/product-community-edition:2.2.5" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.`

Comment: I have finally got it. I used your advice and also removed the replace node as mentioned by @vitoriodachef. My install of Magento had all its code in /app and /lib folders. Once upgraded they were in the /vandor/magento folder along with the default and luma themes, this caused a conflict so had to delete them and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try upgrading from Magento admin panel by navigating to below location:

> 'System' > 'Tools' > 'Web setup wizard'

Comment: I've tried that, it won't let me upgrade